# Sql query excute only if one column has 0 value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `scaricomerci` with these columns: `id | date | qt | price | vat`

My query is:

```
SELECT SUM ((price * vat / 100) * qt) as totalvat FROM `scaricomerci`
```

I need this query to be launched just in case `qt = 0`.

I would have the sum of every row in the table where the field "qt" is difference from 0 zero. I need a "if-then" construct that checks the value of "qt", if = 0 don't add the value to SUM

Comment: What do you mean by: "otherwise how can I do anything?"

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing sample data and desired output.

Comment: Sorry for my english! I would have the sum of evrey row in the table where the field "qt" is difference from 0 zero. I need a "if-then" costruct that check the value of "qt", if = 0 don't add the value to SUM

Comment: Please add this information to your question, don't put it in comments.

Comment: Use a where clause.  But multiplying with qt when qt equals zero would cause the record to participate with zero to the sum anyway. So the where clause would merely be an opportunity for the query engine to optimize the query plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if` with `qt = 0` check:

```
select sum (price * vat * if(qt = 0, 1, qt) / 100) as totalvat 
from `scaricomerci`
```

Comment: In this case query doesn't include rows with qt = 0, but this seems that he would like return it too, but without applying sum (price * vat * qt / 100) on rows with qt=0

Comment: @Alexander Ravikovich: that makes more sense (_but still not enough_).